# Set CefSharp to single-process mode programmatically

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

CefSharp allows to be started in single-process mode when passing the command line argument `--single-process`. Is there a way to enable this from the application itself (programmatically, on startup, by default)?

I don't see it anywhere in CefSharp's code. The flag might be captured somewhere lower-level.

Comment: Came up with a quick hack - check the arguments in Main(), if not present, relaunch with the flag. Wish there was a better way...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Single Process` mode is not supported in `CefSharp` (It's not supported in `CEF` either) so we don't expose a way to programmatically set the relevant property.

http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/_cef_settings_t.html#single_process

There are many scenarios where things just crash. See http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=13259&p=28501#p28501 for one such example.

Basically use at your own risk.